# slack api（delete.chat)について

Tags: python, api, slack

slackでpythonを用いたapiを作りたいです。
内容としては、特定のchannelのメッセージを削除するものです。

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
import time

hist_url = "https://slack.com/api/channels.history"
delete_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.delete"

token = 'chat:writeのtoken'
channel = 'チャンネルのid'

hist_params = {
    'channel' : channel,
    'token' : token,
    'count' : '200'
}

req = urllib.request.Request(hist_url)
hist_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(hist_params).encode('ascii')
req.data = hist_params

res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

body = res.read()
data = json.loads(body)

for m in data["message"]:
    if (m['user'] == 'USLACKBOT'):
        print(m)
        delete_params = {
            'channel' : channel,
            'token' : token,
            'ts' :  m["ts"]
        }
        req = urllib.request.Request(delete_url)
        delete_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(delete_params).encode('ascii')
        req.data = delete_params

        res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        body = res.read()

        print(body)

        time.sleep(2)
```

エラーとして

```
line 27, in <module>
    for m in data["message"]:
KeyError: 'message'
[Finished in 0.771s]
```

が出ます。
messageの部分を変えれば良いのかよく分からないので、教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `message` ではなくて `messages`(複数形)ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ”messages"にしても同様のエラーが出てきてしまいました。

Comment: そうなりますと、`urllib.request.urlopen(req)` か `body = res.read()` の段階でエラーが発生している可能性があります。例外処理(try 〜 except)を追加して、実際にエラーが発生しているかどうかを確認してみると良いかと思います。